# HTACCESS- Rewriting URL working, but need to ignore folder

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess

I am using my .htaccess file to rewrite the path to my CSS file:

```
RewriteRule ^assets/css/min/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)\.css$ assets/css/min.php?style=$1&layout=$2&ver=$3 [L,QSA]
```

So, `http://www.example.com/assets/css/min.php?style=blue&layout=flat` can be accessed at `http://www.example.com/assets/css/min/blue/flat/1-0.css`

The problem I am having is that the images to my styles reside at:

`/assets/css/img/`

So in my CSS file, if I have a style like:

```
.mobile-menu-logo { 
  display: block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('img/mobile-menu-logo.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

... I get a page not found.

How can I use these .htaccess rules, but still have access to the /img folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have this rule at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(assets/css)/.+/(img/.+)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/assets/css/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Answer (score 0):

Put a .htaccess file in the root of the folder you need to ignore, with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```